# How to accept or reject the call using voice control in android

Tags: android

I want to accept or reject the call using voice command.

For example:-
    when receiving a call just voice command as accept then the call want to answer to the user.

Comment: use broadcastreceiver

Comment: can you give any sample code for voice control